# what's the issue in using Render Props with React.PureComponent as mentioned in the react official docs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Can someone explain in a bit more detailed way why using Render Props with React.PureComponent will generate a new value for the render prop in each render?

docs link: https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#use-render-props-for-cross-cutting-concerns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when React renders -> `mouse => (<Cat mouse={mouse}/>)` is going to be a new reference every render.

The fix by placing inside another function `renderTheCat`, it's going to be the same.

Anther way of thinking of it `(()=>{}) === (()=>{})` will always equal false.  Were as `renderTheCat === renderTheCat` equals true.

Comment: So to get around we are creating renderTheCat as a class instance, so it remains same in every render right?

Comment: @discoveranirban  A function, but yes, by doing this it remains the same.